# Vue3 - Component not showing in View

Tags: vuejs3

the contents of the subcomponents are not displayed in the browser.

I have implemented the corresponding subcomponents in my view, but no matter how much I have tried to adjust the path, it cannot be found.

Console error: HeaderComponent.vue:4 [Vue Router warn]: No match found for the location with path "/questionnaire"

My indes.js

```
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory} from 'vue-router'




const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHashHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
    routes: [
    {
      path: '/IndexView',
      name: 'indexView',
      component:() => import('../Views/IndexView.vue'),
  
    },
    {
      path: '/QuestionnaireView',
      name: 'questionnaire',
      component: () => import('../Views/QuestionnaireView.vue'),
  
    },
    {
      path: '/ProductsView',
      name: 'Products',
      component: () => import('../Views/ProductsView.vue'),
  
    },
  
    {
      path: '/AboutView',
      name: 'About',
      component: () => import('../Views/AboutView.vue'),
  
    },
  
    ]
  });
  
  export default router;
```

my main.js

```
* import the fontawesome core */
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'

/* import font awesome icon component */
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { far } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'

/* import specific icons */
import { faUserSecret } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { faTwitter } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'
import { faFacebook } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'



/* add icons to the library */
library.add(faUserSecret, faTwitter, faFacebook, fas, fab, far)


createApp(App).component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon).use(router).mount('#app')
```

View Component

```
<script setup>
import  Questionnaire  from '../components/Questionnaire.vue'
import HeaderComponent from '../HeaderComponent.vue';
</script>


<template>
    <main>
        <Questionnaire />
    </main>
</template>
```

The subcomponent

```
<template>
    <div>
      <div v-if="currentQuestionIndex === 0">
        <h2>Which feature do you need?</h2>
        <label v-for="(answer, index) in question1Answers" :key="index">
          <input type="radio" name="question1" :value="answer">{{ answer }}
        </label>
        <button @click="nextQuestion()">Next</button>
      </div>
      <div v-else-if="currentQuestionIndex === 1">
        <h2>Which product are you working with?</h2>
        <label v-for="(answer, index) in question2Answers" :key="index">
          <input type="radio" name="question2" :value="answer">{{ answer }}
        </label>
        <button @click="nextQuestion()">Next</button>
      </div>
      <div v-else-if="currentQuestionIndex === 2">
        <h2>Do you need GUI and mimic settings preset for sanding?</h2>
        <label v-for="(answer, index) in question3Answers" :key="index">
          <input type="radio" name="question3" :value="answer">{{ answer }}
        </label>
        <button @click="nextQuestion()">Next</button>
      </div>
      <div v-else-if="currentQuestionIndex === 3">
        <h2>Is the product you are working with targeted at robot first timers?</h2>
        <label v-for="(answer, index) in question4Answers" :key="index">
          <input type="radio" name="question4" :value="answer">{{ answer }}
        </label>
        <button @click="nextQuestion()">Next</button>
      </div>
      <div v-else-if="currentQuestionIndex === 4">
        <h2>Do you need intuitive joystick/system that gives more feed back when processing?</h2>
        <label v-for="(answer, index) in question5Answers" :key="index">
          <input type="radio" name="question5" :value="answer">{{ answer }}
        </label>
        <button @click="nextQuestion()">Next</button>
      </div>
      <div v-else-if="currentQuestionIndex === 5">
        <h2>Do you need the possibility to include a industrial touch screen?</h2>
        <label v-for="(answer, index) in question6Answers" :key="index">
          <input type="radio" name="question6" :value="answer">{{ answer }}
        </label>
        <button @click="nextQuestion()">Next</button>
      </div>
      <div v-else>
        <h2>Results</h2>
        <p>You chose: {{ results }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
  
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
        currentQuestionIndex: 0,
        question1Answers: ['Sanding', 'Grinding', 'Spray painting', 'Deburring', 'Polishing'],
        question2Answers: ['Wood + composite', 'Textile', 'Metal', 'Plastic'],
        question3Answers: ['Yes', 'No'],
        question4Answers: ['Yes', 'No'],
        question5Answers: ['Yes', 'No'],
        question6Answers: ['Yes', 'No'],
        results: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        nextQuestion() {
            let selectedAnswer
            switch (this.currentQuestionIndex) {
                case 0:
                    selectedAnswer = document.querySelector('input[name="question1"]:checked')
                    break
                case 1:
                    selectedAnswer = document.querySelector('input[name="question2"]:checked')
                    break
                case 2:
                    selectedAnswer = document.querySelector('input[name="question3"]:checked')
                    break
                case 3:
                    selectedAnswer = document.querySelector('input[name="question4"]:checked')
                    break
                case 4:
                    selectedAnswer = document.querySelector('input[name="question5"]:checked')
                    break
                case 5:
                    selectedAnswer = document.querySelector('input[name="question6"]:checked')
                    break
            }
            if (selectedAnswer) {
                switch (this.currentQuestionIndex) {
                case 0:
                    this.results += selectedAnswer.value + ', '
                    break
                case 1:
                    this.results += selectedAnswer.value + ', '
                    break
                case 2:
                    this.results += selectedAnswer.value + ', '
                    break
                case 3:
                    this.results += selectedAnswer.value + ', '
                    break
                case 4:
                    this.results += selectedAnswer.value + ', '
                    break
                case 5:
                    this.results += selectedAnswer.value
                    break
                }
                this.currentQuestionIndex++
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

App.vue

```
<script setup>
import { RouterView } from 'vue-router'
import HeaderComponent from './components/HeaderComponent.vue';
</script>

<template>
  <header>
    <HeaderComponent/>
  </header>

  <RouterView />
</template>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you attempt to navigate to "View Component"?  I think somewhere you're trying to navigate to `/questionnaire` but there is no exact match in your router index.js.  The closest match would be `/QuestionnaireView` so you probably want to set your navigation to that path instead (or alternatively, change your route config)

Comment: I want to show my QuestionnaireView who got the questionnaire component inside. am I supposed to route to the component? but there will be mutible components inside the view. sorry if I'm being stupid

Comment: According to your router index.js, the `QuestionnaireView` can be seen by going to `http://localhost:5173/#/QuestionnaireView`.  That URL should render App.vue with `<RouterView />` replaced with the `<QuestionnaireView />` component.  If that component contains sub-components, they will also be rendered.